# Pydantic field with default value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, typing, pydantic

Let's say I have the following singleton:

```
from typing import Union, TypeVar
from typing import Literal
from pydantic import BaseModel


class UnidentifiedType(BaseModel):
    _instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        if UnidentifiedType._instance is None:
            Unidentified._instance = self

    @property
    def instance(self):
        if self._instance is None:
            UnidentifiedType()
        return self._instance

Unidentified = UnidentifiedType.instance
```

Then I make the following typing alias:

```
Identifiable = Union[Literal[Unidentified], TypeVar("T")]
```

I already know that I can make a model and give a field `bar` a default value of `Unidentified` like this:

```
class foo(BaseModel):
    bar: Identifiable[str] = Unidentified
```

But how do I make it so that *any field of type Indentifiable[something]* has a default value of `Unidentified`?

In other words, is there a way to do:

```
class foo(BaseModel):
    bar: Identifiable[str]
```

And have `bar` still have a default value of `Unidentified`?